# FlatFileItemReader goes reading same files after processing the files

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am writing one Spring Batch job scheduler. I need to read multiple files of some specific pattern for this i configured the xml like below...

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader1"
        class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
        <property name="resources"
            value="file:#{ fileLocation + '/FILE1*.txt'}" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="itemReader1" />
        <property name="saveState" value="false" />
    </bean>
<bean id="itemReader1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="strict" value="false" />
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="prefixMatchingLineMapper1" />
    </bean>
```

where filelocation is jndi string value.

**Issue:** When i deploy the code on application server which runs every after 15 minutes , after reading some files like FILE1_2015_03_04.txt , processing is done and these files to be archived.Now the fileLocation not having the previous files or may be having different files name , but spring batch try to read the same files FILE1_2015_03_04.txt and the warning comes - doOpen "Input resource does not exist ".

**Update from comments**
I have configured the cron scheduler and below is the config for job:

```
<batch:job id="ioSampleJob" restartable="false">
  <batch:step id="step1">
    <batch:tasklet>
      <batch:transaction-attributes propagation="NEVER" />
      <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader1" writer="itemWriter1" chunk-completion-policy="completionPolicy" /> 
    </batch:tasklet> 
  </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Pls help to resolve the issue.
Thanks Vishal

Comment: how do you run the batch? and please show the step configuration as well

Comment: Thanks Michael for your prompt comment, I have configured the cron scheduler and below is the config for job-                                                   <batch:job id="ioSampleJob" restartable="false">
  <batch:step id="step1">
   <batch:tasklet>
    <batch:transaction-attributes
     propagation="NEVER" />
    <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader1"               writer="itemWriter1"
     chunk-completion-policy="completionPolicy" />
   </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
 </batch:job>

Comment: Also want to add this job called from one JobLauncher configured in JobDetailBean programmatically and there is one condition in the current job to run another job program, thanks

Comment: Can you elobarate your scenario bit more? do mean to say first run and subsequent run reads same file? or in the first run itself it repeatatively reads same file and also can you copy your cron expression aswell, sometimes inproper configuration of cron expression would trigger multiple jobs at sametime.

Comment: Hi Karthik , First job runs through JobLaunher and Second jobs run when some condition met in first job run , otherwise only first job runs only.

Comment: is the SkipListener give the way to remove the resource which was failed during processing ?

Comment: How is the old file removed?

Comment: Hi Michael , files are archived using the fileutils cleanDirectory method.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit later, but if you be here it is because you are facing this problem yet like me.
To solve this problem you should create a bean of FileSystemResource in separete way in your xml.

```
<bean id="customFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" ref="customFile"/><!-- avoid use directly jobParams here -->
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="0" />
    <property name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    <property name="comments" value="*, \u001A" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="br.com.sample.batch.CustomFieldSetMapperSIAW"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="customFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters[arquivoGSIN]}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```